# How to reassign a value of a key in a javascript dictionary for onChange of a TextField tag?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dictionary, material-ui, textfield

This is the schema for my model:

```
const workoutSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  workouts: [
    {
      workoutName: String,
      sets: Number,
      reps: Number,
      weight: Number,
    },
  ],
});
```

This is the postData that is reference in the text field below.

```
const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
    workouts: [{ workoutName: "", sets: "", reps: "", weight: "" }],
  });
```

to access the workoutName above, *Below* I have set the value to `postData.workouts["workoutName"]` seems to work but unsure. I am having trouble on the *onChange* property, specifically with the second argument in *setPostData* `[workoutName]: e.target.value`. I am having trouble accessing the `workoutName` key within the workouts dictionary from the schema.

```
<TextField
              label="Workout"
              variant="outlined"
              value={postData.workouts["workoutName"]}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setPostData({ ...postData, workoutName: e.target.value })
              }
```

I have tried `workouts["workoutName"]: e.target.value` but I get a syntax error before the bracket saying it was expecting an `,`. [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEihT.png). I have also tried `workouts.workoutName : e.target.value` like in other languages but not worked. How can I access the workoutName in workouts object to reassign it to the value typed in the text field (ie: `e.target.value`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postData is an object

workouts is a property of this object

workout name is a property inside an array that is a property of workouts

So, in order to change the workout name you need to do:

```
{...postData, workouts: [{...postData.workouts[0], workoutName: e.target.value}]}
```

To read the workout name you need to do:

```
postData.workouts[0].name
```

Comment: ooo thank you for the reply, I tried it but now app crashes on the value part. `Value={postData.workouts["workoutName"]}` gives error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'workoutName')" also tried " value={postData.workouts[0].workoutName}" but gives out same error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Added the code for reading the name to the answer

Comment: get error: 
```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')                          41 | <TextField
                                                                      42    label="Workout"
                                                                       43    variant="outlined"
                                                                  > 44    value={postData.workouts[0].workoutName}                              ^ 45 |   onChange={(e) =>setPostData({...postData.workouts[0]```

Comment: Line 44 returns an error

Comment: It should work, look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-allen-r8f3-r8f3b) example, see if you are doing everything right

Comment: yes everything is correct I even changed your sand box to my set up and the same error happened here is the link to the image of how I set it up ```https://imgur.com/a/ttjGifW```. As soon as you type into the text field it crashes.

Comment: You missed one part of my answer on the `onChange` function, it should be:

`
          setPostData({
            ...postData,
            workouts: [{ ...postData.workouts[0], workoutName: e.target.value }]
          });
`

Comment: wow I don't know how i missed that thank you for the help!!!! Much appreciated Happy holidays!